# Deserialise multiple JSON Array - VB.net

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I am using VB.Net and Newtonsoft.JSON tools work on a Json structure. I'm trying to deserialise the Json into a class definition. The Json structure has two arrays. The first array is just a sequence number ID (with no label) which has within it multiple @attributes. An example of json structure is shown below.

```
{"142456":[{"@attributes":{"tag1":"Benitez",
    "tag2":"1989",
    "tag3":"",
    "tag4":"tall",
    "tag5":"red"
}},
{"@attributes":{"tag1":"Franco",
    "tag2":"1984",
    "tag3":"",
    "tag4":"short",
    "tag5":"grey"
}},
{"@attributes":{"tag1":"Jones",
    "tag2":"1956",
    "tag3":"",
    "tag4":"big",
    "tag5":"brown"
}}],
"456782":[{"@attributes":{"tag1":"Smith",
    "tag2":"1952",
    "tag3":"",
    "tag4":"small",
    "tag5":"green"
}},
{"@attributes":{"tag1":"Walton",
    "tag2":"1980",
    "tag3":"",
    "tag4":"high",
    "tag5":"yellow"
}},
{"@attributes":{"tag1":"Kelly",
"tag2":"1978",
"tag3":"",
"tag4":"average",
"tag5":"black"
}}]
<.... continuing with more items>
}
```

I have devised a basic class structure to deserialise the Json into.

```
Public Class MainClass
    Private m_attributes As Attributes
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="@attributes")> _
    Public Property attributes As Attributes
        Get
            Return m_attributes
        End Get
        Set(value As Attributes)
            m_attributes = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class Attributes
    Private m_tag1 As String
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="tag1")> _
    Public Property tag1() As String
        Get
            Return m_tag1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_tag1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_tag2 As String
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="tag2")> _
    Public Property tag2() As String
        Get
            Return m_tag2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_tag2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
:
:
End Class
```

If I remove the first array from the Json string (ie exclude the sequence number IDs) and just have the @attributes I can return an JSON array of the attributes using this.

> Dim JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MainClass())(Json)

The problem I cant work out is how to redefine the class or JSON object to be able to deserialise both arrays.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error Andrew. I have now corrected it. "Smith" should be the value for "tag1" property.

Comment: Also suggestion to try Paste Special in VS is just giving repeating classes like   Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property _142456() As _142456
    Public Property _456782() As _456782
End Class

Comment: I see there's another post which uses dictionary to deserialise non unique property names. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932943/deserializing-json-without-unique-property-name

But its not multi-dimensional

Answer (score 0):

After various trial and error attempts the solution I came up with was to use a Dictionary to contain the inner array of json objects which I had already devised.

Creating the dictionary:-

```
Dim JSONObj As Dictionary(Of String, MainClass()) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, MainClass()))(Json)
```

Hope this helps someone else!